# How to check if Data Type equals Generic Data Type and assign to Property if True?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

**Context**

I have a `Generic Swift Class` containing a `component Property` of the `Generic Type`.
A few other `Variables` with different `Data Types` are passed through the `Initializer`, however, all of them are conforming to the `Generic Protocol`.

However, I get the following `Compiler Error` in `Line 11`:

> 'ComponentA' is not convertible to 'C'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component { ... }

struct ComponentA: Component { ... }
struct ComponentB: Component { ... }

class Main<C: Component> {
    var component: C

    init(componentA: ComponentA, componentB: ComponentB) {
        // I am trying to check, whether componentA equals the Generic Data Type and assign it to the component Property if true.
        if case let safeComponent = componentA as C {
            self.component = safeComponent
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal of checking whether a `Data Type` equals the `Generic Data Type` and assign it to the `component Property` if true?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this? It feels like an odd thing to do and I wonder if either you don’t actually need to do this or there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks for your answer, the reason behind it is, that the `Class Main` is actually an `ObservableObject` created by a `Generic SwiftUI View` with the same `Generic Data Type`. The `component Property` is also `Published` and used in another `Generic SwiftUI View` with the same `Generic Data Type`. Hope this explains the use case, couldn't think of a better solution. Any input is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 3 possible approaches. All deal with the possibility that `componentA` can not be cast to C

```
protocol Component {  }

struct ComponentA: Component {  }
struct ComponentB: Component {  }

// optional `component`
class Main1<C: Component> {
    var component: C?

    init?(componentA: ComponentA, componentB: ComponentB) {
        if let safeComponent = componentA as? C {
            self.component = safeComponent
        }
    }
}

// init throws when precondtions not met
class Main2<C: Component> {

    enum Errors: Error {
        case preconditionsNotSatisfied
    }

    var component: C

    init(componentA: ComponentA, componentB: ComponentB) throws {
        if let safeComponent = componentA as? C {
            self.component = safeComponent
        } else {
            throw Errors.preconditionsNotSatisfied
        }
    }
}


// init can return nil
class Main3<C: Component> {
    var component: C

    init?(componentA: ComponentA, componentB: ComponentB) {
        if let safeComponent = componentA as? C {
            self.component = safeComponent
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to Check for componentA compatibility with C. For example :

```
protocol Component {
    var name: String {get}
    
}

struct ComponentNil: Component {
    var name: String
}

struct ComponentA: Component {
    var name: String
    var a: Int
}
struct ComponentB: Component {
    var name: String
    var b: Int
}

class Main<C: Component> {
    var component: C
    
    init(componentA: ComponentA, componentB: ComponentB) {
        // Check that componentA is compatible with type C
        if let safeComponent = componentA as? C {
            self.component = safeComponent
        } else {
            // force componentB to be of type C
            self.component = componentB as! C
            // not that this may throw an error
        }
    }
}
```